# Managing python version when creating anaconda env on offline linux server

Tags: python, anaconda, version, clone, offline

What I want to do is just creating an anaconda environment exactly identical with the base environment in terms of python version and list of installed packages.
I am working on an offline linux server (CentOS7).

I tried the following code

```
conda create -n myenv --offline
```

but it created an empty environment with python 2, which is the default python version of the linux system, instead of python 3, which is installed in the base environment of anaconda.

Why does it change the python version when I create a new env? How can I manage the python version of a new env?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

p.s.

I also tried several codes like

```
conda create -n myenv --clone base
```

but it stack to fetching package files from online server, which is impossible for the offline server and ends up with failure.

Comment: `conda create -n myenv python=3` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it didn't work. It seemed it tried to connect to the internet and failed because it is an offline server.